# Java list only addition no deletion

Tags: java, collections

I want to know if there is any possibility that we can create a Java java.util.List which only allows the addition of element but doesn't allow the removal of elements?

One way I am thinking of overriding remove method. Please suggest.

Comment: Why go to all the effort of stopping a programmer from using remove? Or if you're implementing a custom object that inherits the List interface, simply override remove as a function that does nothing. The hassle in creating a different List object to stop removal seems unnecessary?

Comment: Simplest approach would be to sub-class one of the existing List implementations and override the remove method.

Comment: Agreed to overwrite list class, but instead of doing nothing I'd suggest raising an exception, so the users know they're doing something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be achieved using Decorator pattern. This way it could be applied to all container that implement `List`:

```
private static class UnremovableList<E> implements  List<E> {
    private List<E> innerContainer;

    public UnremovableList(List<E> original) {
        innerContainer = original
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int location, E object) {
        innerContainer.add(location, object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E object) {
        return innerContainer.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int location, Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        return innerContainer.addAll(location, collection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        return innerContainer.addAll(collection);
    } - 

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object object) {
        return innerContainer.contains(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        return innerContainer.containsAll(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int location) {
        return innerContainer.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object object) {
        return innerContainer.indexOf(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return innerContainer.isEmpty();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return listIterator(0);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            Iterator<E> iterator = innerContainer.iterator();

            @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override public E next() {
                return iterator.next();
            }

            @Override public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int location) {
        return new ListIterator<E>() {
            ListIterator<E> iterator = innerContainer.listIterator(location);

            @Override public void add(E object) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override public boolean hasPrevious() {
                return iterator.hasPrevious();
            }

            @Override public E next() {
                return iterator.next();
            }

            @Override public int nextIndex() {
                return iterator.nextIndex();
            }

            @Override public E previous() {
                return iterator.previous();
            }

            @Override public int previousIndex() {
                return iterator.previousIndex();
            }

            @Override public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override public void set(E object) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object object) {
        return innerContainer.lastIndexOf(object);
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int location) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int location, E object) {
        return innerContainer.set(location, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return innerContainer.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<E> subList(int start, int end) {
        return new UnremovableList(innerContainer.subList(start, end));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return innerContainer.toArray();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
        return innerContainer.toArray(array);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<String> stableList = new UnremovableList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

Comment: Bonus points for favoring composition over inheritance, and for minding the iterators. `subList()` would probably need a similar treatment, though.

Comment: @JiriTousek thanks. I've wrapped original `subList()` with `UnremovableList` - so now it should work

Answer (score 4):

You can extend an existing List implementing class and override all public deleting methods, but it are quite a few methods to override (maybe even more, below are all I've found quickly)

```
public class UnDeletableList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }

    // OPTIONAL IN CASE OF EXTRA STRICTNESS
    @Override
    public void replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> u) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
   }

    @Override
    public E set(int i, E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("don't remove from this list");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would throw `UnsupportedOperationException` rather than silently do nothing, which will cause discontent for other devs when they discover your code after trying to debug why their calls to remove seem to not work.

Comment: Depends on OP's definition of "removing" elements, but you might also want to forbid `set(int, E)` and `replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E>)` (since Java 8)

Comment: Added this to the answer @Bohemian

Comment: And yours too @tobias_k

Comment: `ArrayList` has a few more methods, like `trimToSize`; also, `subList` will return sort of a view to the list, i.e. if you remove from a sublist, you also remove from the backing array of the original list (but it also seems to inherit the restrictions from the original list).

Comment: Yeah, as I said in the answer.. There are many deleting methods.. I think there are even more manipulating methods - so overriding all of them will be a mess in the long run. @tobias_k